# What is the difference between Apache Kafka, RabbitMQ, and Akka in terms of queuing?

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-kafka, queue, akka, backend

I was going to use one of them in my project for queuing users for doing some functions, so they will not do them simultaneously, can anyone explain them to me? What are your recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a pretty broad question, and one that's difficult to answer without more detail about what your *particular* requirements are, existing technology landscape, throughput requirements, etc etc.

Here's a couple of resources that might help, but I think you need to do a bit more research of your own.

- https://www.confluent.io/whitepaper/comparing-confluent-platform-with-traditional-messaging-middleware/
- https://softwaremill.com/mqperf/

Comment: Please note that Software Mills's methodology for testing RabbitMQ uses only one queue, which limits concurrency within the server. If your use-case is more complicated than one queue sending messages (and most are), RabbitMQ should be evaluated as such.

Comment: In general throwing all these technologies into one bucket does not really make sense. Akka is not a message queue, and other caveats could be said about other tech mentioned above. I agree with @Robin here that the question should include the actual use case, then suggestions about what fits and what not could be made.